# Python OpenCV Mediapipe Overlay Triangle on landmark on face

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

I am wanting to take a triangle from an image and overlay it at the same location on my face in video camera.

I am using python mediapipe to get the landmarks and it seems I am able to get the correct triangle, but it doesn't overlay on the correct location properly.

Mediapipe landmarks:
[Landmarks](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11573490/109521608-72aeed00-7ae8-11eb-9539-e07c406cc65b.jpg)

Here is myimage:

[image: myimage]

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import mediapipe as mp

# PROBLEM: There is a problem here It places it in the wrong place and it seems to be drawing a square,
# but without transparency.
def overlay_triangle_in_xyz_postions(source_image, triangle_image, array_xx_yy_zz: []):

    if source_image.shape[2] == 3:
        source_image = cv2.cvtColor(source_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

    if triangle_image.shape[2] == 3:
        triangle_image = cv2.cvtColor(triangle_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

    # Get your mediapipe landmarks - replace this with actual landmark detection
    # https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11573490/109521608-72aeed00-7ae8-11eb-9539-e07c406cc65b.jpg
    # you can vide the landmarks here.
    # landmarks = np.array([[100, 100], [200, 100], [150, 200]])
    landmarks = np.array(array_xx_yy_zz)

    # Assuming the triangle_image is an equilateral triangle,
    # we'll set the vertices to be the top middle and bottom corners
    triangle_vertices = np.array([[triangle_image.shape[1] / 2, 0], [0, triangle_image.shape[0]],
                                  [triangle_image.shape[1], triangle_image.shape[0]]])

    # Get the affine transform matrix
    M = cv2.getAffineTransform(triangle_vertices.astype(np.float32), landmarks.astype(np.float32))

    # Separate the alpha channel from the rest of the triangle image
    triangle_image_rgb = triangle_image[:, :, :3]
    triangle_image_alpha = triangle_image[:, :, 3]

    # Warp the triangle image (RGB channels only) to fit the landmarks
    warped_triangle_rgb = cv2.warpAffine(triangle_image_rgb, M, (source_image.shape[1], source_image.shape[0]))

    # Warp the triangle image (alpha channel only) to fit the landmarks
    warped_triangle_alpha = cv2.warpAffine(triangle_image_alpha, M, (source_image.shape[1], source_image.shape[0]))

    # Recombine the RGB and alpha channels
    warped_triangle = cv2.merge([warped_triangle_rgb, warped_triangle_alpha])

    # Normalize the alpha mask to keep intensity between 0 and 1
    alpha = warped_triangle[:, :, 3].astype(float) / 255

    # Create 3 channel alpha mask
    alpha = cv2.merge([alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha])

    # Alpha blending
    final_image = (alpha * warped_triangle + (1 - alpha) * source_image).astype(np.uint8)

    return final_image


def get_triangle_from_image():
    image_element = cv2.imread("./myface.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image_element, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = face_mesh.process(image)

    # Check if any face is detected
    if results.multi_face_landmarks:
        for face_landmarks in results.multi_face_landmarks:
            # Get the coordinates of the landmarks for the triangle
            landmarks = [[int(face_landmarks.landmark[i].x * image.shape[1]),
                          int(face_landmarks.landmark[i].y * image.shape[0])] for i in [10, 108, 151]]

    triangle_image_rbg = extract_triangle_from_landmarks(image, landmarks)
    triangle_image = cv2.cvtColor(triangle_image_rbg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)

    # This should return a triangle with alpha channel
    return triangle_image


def extract_triangle_from_landmarks(image, landmarks):
    # Create a mask for the image
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

    # Draw the triangle on the mask
    triangle_cnt = np.array(landmarks).reshape((-1, 1, 2)).astype(np.int32)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [triangle_cnt], 0, (255, 255, 255), -1)

    # Bitwise-and the mask and the original image to get the triangle
    triangle_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)

    # Create bounding rectangle around the triangle
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(triangle_cnt)

    # Crop the image using the bounding rectangle
    triangle_image = triangle_image[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    return triangle_image


def overlay_triangle(face_image, triangle_image, landmarks):
    # Get the size of the triangle_image
    h, w = triangle_image.shape[:2]

    # Create a mask for the triangle_image
    mask = np.zeros((h, w), dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, np.array([[0, 0], [w // 2, h], [w, 0]], dtype=np.int32), 255)

    # Compute the bounding rectangle for the triangle
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(np.array(landmarks))

    # Adjust the landmarks to the bounding rectangle
    landmarks = [[x[0] - x, x[1] - y] for x in landmarks]

    # Compute the affine transform that maps the triangle_image to the face_image
    warp_mat = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32([[0, 0], [w // 2, h], [w, 0]]), np.float32(landmarks))

    # Warp the triangle_image to match the triangle on the face_image
    warped_image = cv2.warpAffine(triangle_image, warp_mat, (face_image.shape[1], face_image.shape[0]))

    # Create a mask for the triangle on the face_image
    mask = cv2.warpAffine(mask, warp_mat, (face_image.shape[1], face_image.shape[0]))

    # Use the mask to blend the warped_image into the face_image
    face_image = cv2.bitwise_and(face_image, cv2.bitwise_not(cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)))
    face_image = cv2.bitwise_or(face_image, cv2.bitwise_and(warped_image, cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)))

    return face_image


# Initialize MediaPipe Face Mesh
mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh
face_mesh = mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh()

# Start the webcam feed
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Strip out ALPHA for processing.
    image = bgr_image = frame[:, :, :3]

    results = face_mesh.process(image)

    # Check if any face is detected
    if results.multi_face_landmarks:
        triangle = get_triangle_from_image()

        for face_landmarks in results.multi_face_landmarks:
            # PROBLEM ? This might be icorrect...
            a = 10
            b = 151
            c = 108
            ret_frame = overlay_triangle_in_xyz_postions(image, triangle, [[a, a], [b, a], [c, b]] )

            cv2.imshow('Triangle', ret_frame)
            break

    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```